# Can a USB stick or a host adaptor know if the stick is safe to remove?

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive, usb-hub, safely-remove-hardware

I sometimes work quite intensely with a large number of memory sticks, perhaps 16 at a time, that need to be mounted, content synchronised, and removed for continued use. Right now under Windows I need to identify the drive that has completed copying its data, safely remove, and pull the correct stick. Since all sticks are identical this can be a significant challenge that is easily done wrong. Ideally a docking station could a) request the dismount of a particular stick and b) have a light per stick indicating it is safe to do so. Alternately the stick itself could perform this role, but would mean only being able to use that one stick type.

Is it possible for a memory stick or docking station to do this? Do products exist already?

Comment: Only the OS (-> the software) knows if it is safe to remove an USB drive or not. As it depends only on software there is AFAIK no hardware interface for querying or requesting a safe removal. If you want to control this develop a software that communicates with the OS and your "docking station" (e.g. switch off or on an LED if a stick is safe for removal).

Comment: @Robert - agreed.  I used to do this in a 'one stick at a time' mode, using the disk activity  light on the dock so I could pull it when it was done, not when the OS thought it was done. "Safe eject, what's that?" ;) [using FAT so safe is as safe does.]

Comment: Modern versions of Windows have mitigated the need to specifically eject removable flash drives.  It's one of the reasons that UI has changed significantly.